# Find all solutions of $\left[\ln(\sin^{-1}(e^x))\right]^5=\ln(\sin^{-1}(e^x))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, logarithms

> > The question is: Find all solutions of $\left[\ln(\sin^{-1}(e^x))\right]^5=\ln(\sin^{-1}(e^x))$, where $x$ is real.
> >
> > Give the solutions in exact form.

What I have done
$$\left[\ln(\sin^{-1}(e^x))\right]^5=\ln(\sin^{-1}(e^x))$$

Let $z = \ln(\sin^{-1}(e^x))$

$$ \Leftrightarrow z^5=z$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  z^5-z=0 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  z(z^4-1) = 0 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow z(z^2-1)(z^2+1)=0 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow z(z+1)(z-1)(z+i)(z-i)=0 $$

$$ \because  z \in R $$

$$ \Rightarrow z = 0,1,-1 $$

Hence

$$ \ln(\sin^{-1}(e^x))=0 ~~, ~ \ln(\sin^{-1}(e^x))=1  ~~ , ~ \ln(\sin^{-1}(e^x)) =-1$$

$$ \therefore x =\ln(\sin(1)) ~ , \ln(\sin(e)) , ~ \ln(\sin(\frac{1}{e}))$$

However checking my answers only $2$ are valid.

These are $ x=\ln(\sin(\frac{1}{e}))$ and $ x =\ln(\sin(1))$

My question is why $x=\ln(\sin(e))$ invalid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the real function $\arcsin$ has domain $[-1,1]$ and codomain $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$. $$\ln\arcsin e^x=1\iff \arcsin e^x=e$$

But $e\notin\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$.

Comment: Not that I care per se, but why the downvote? Is there a problem with the answer?

Comment: I have not seen the downvote and I guess it has been neutralized by some upvote. But I can assure you that it had been made for a sick person.

Comment: Yes, it's been neutralised. I left there the question in hope of receiving an answer.

Comment: Hey could you explain that more simply , I'm a high school student so I'm still confused about what your comment means.

Comment: The definition of $\arcsin x$, for $-1\le x\le 1$, is "the one and only $\theta$ such that $-\frac\pi2\le \theta\le \frac\pi2$ and $\sin \theta=x$". Since $e>\frac\pi2$, the equation $\arcsin e^x=e$ does not have solution.

Comment: just for reference i did not down vote your answer is far more exact.

Comment: @shaihorowitz Never thought you did, and it's already been neutralised. Truth to be told, I don't feel like this answer deserves +4 to begin with. :)

Answer (score 1):

Think about what it would mean for $ln(sin^{-1}(e^x))$ to have a positive value. you should be able to convince yourself that for it to have a positive value $x$ contains an imaginary part. You can do this by going through the domain and ranges of all functions contained for a start note $e^x$ is always greater than 0 for all real $x$. You will eventually see that if $ln(sin^{-1}(e^x))$ = 1 then x must be complex.

In short $∵z∈R$ step is slightly wrong.